# Inspect result of SCons Configure

Tags: scons

How to access result of `Configure` check in SCons?

```
conf = env.Configure(**configure_args)
have_deps = conf.CheckLib("png") and conf.CheckLib("vorbisfile")
env = conf.Finish()
```

Is there anything that I can check in `env` to see if `png` library is available?

Answer (score 1):

Save the result in the environment variables.

```
env["HAVE_DEPS"] = have_deps
```

Comment: So, no automatic place where Configure saves its status?

Comment: I didn't check the intern code for this. But i'm using SCons for a while and I didn't see ant code like that.